# Advance Pagination using jQuery \ Knockout.Js \ JavaScript : "View More Data"

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

I have an array which contains some records of data(from my backend I am retreving this data).

I am using this array to bind a grid. This is achieved using knockout.Js.

My final array which binds to the grid :  `_results(commonData);`

Say for example :

```
function BindData() {
// Go to Backend . get the data and push it to _results.

}
```

Here commonData is an array which contains the data from my backend.
And _results is an observable array.

Here is the structure of my markup :

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: results">
<tr>
<td data-bind="text: Emp ID"></td>
<td data-bind="text: Emp Status"></td>
<td data-bind="text: Emp Dept"></td>
<td data-bind="text: Emp Code"></td>
<td data-bind="text: Emp Address"></td>
<td data-bind="text: Emp Manager"></td>
<td data-bind="text: Emp Reporting Manager"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

This works very much as expected.

I have a variable for row count.

```
var _rowCount = 5;
```

Now : I just want to show 5 records(rows) at a time.
If there are more than 5 records from coming from backend, User should click on "View More" and I want to call My BindData() method.
I should get the data from the server each time. But I should not rebind the existing data.

If there are a total of ten records, I will bind only 5. Clicking on View More should get the next five records and add it to the . The first five should remain as-is.

Any ideas on how this can be implemented?
Suggestions, examples are welcome.

Thanks a lot !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using an observableArray, so you basically wrote your own answer:

```
function BindData() {
    // Go to Backend . get the data and push it to _results.

}
```

Just to work it out a bit more for you:

```
function BindData() {

    var onSuccess = function(data){
        for(var i=0; i<data.length);i++){
            //just push each object onto the observableArray.
            that.results.push(data[i]);


            // you might need to map some stuff here to observable, maybe with the
            // mapping plugin, but basically the same way you got your first 5?
        }
    }

    $.post('get-next-5-url', 'data', onSuccess);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Basically, I am binding the five records on page load. when user clicks on a link "Load More Data", i need to retain these five and again bind the other five. Totally i would be displaying 10 records now. this is what I want to acheieve.

Comment: And that is exactly what this would achieve, your you push the 5 new items to your observable array once the your POST returns successfully. [Just an example](http://jsfiddle.net/955pG/1/) or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Some how this isn't working for me ... I have my entire data in an array : finalData. _results is my knockout observable array. I am pushing the finaData in to my observable array as follows:_results(finalData); for loop, as per the above example                                                      var _rowCount = 5 ;                                               for (var count = 0; count <= _rowCount ; count++)
        {
            //just push each object onto the observableArray.
            //self.results.push((i+1) * self.results().length);
            _results.push(count + 1);
        }

Comment: What are you trying to do? First you set your _results observableArray to your finalData (`_results(finalData)`) and then you push the values 1,2,3,4 and 5 onto your `_results` array, why? Why do you need to go to your backend as you say you do to get the next 5 when you have your entire data allready in finalData?

Comment: Correct. I need not goto backend again. Dont know why am unable to achieve this.  I have the entire data in my finalData array. and I am pushing it to _results. I need to push only first five. When clicked on View more, I need to add another five records to the existing records.

Comment: I have updated this :http://jsfiddle.net/955pG/2/                         self.results = ko.observableArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
results contain total 9 values. But initially I should show only five.
Now, Clicking on "Add" button should show initial 5 and also five more records(in this case, 4 more because totally there are only 9) . Pleaseeee suggest. Thanks a lot!

Comment: several ways to do it, here's two: use two arrays, one for your entire dataset, one for displaying. Each time the user request 5 new ones, push the next five result from one into the other. Or, have a `computed` observable, that depends on an observable which is the showcount which you increase with 5 every time and you use that computed observable in your html